# Is it possible to set default language for infoPlist.strings (App name)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization

I have an iPad app in which I want to localize the application name also.
I know how to do this by adding infoPlist.strings file.
(Suppose) Till now I have added two languages russian and English which are working fine.
Now the question is for any other I want to set russian name as default. Like If I choose french then the app name should be in russian , if russian then russian and if English then only the app name should be in English..

Let me know if you need more info.
Currently I am using the below code.

```
    NSUserDefaults *localeDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [localeDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    NSString *currentDeviceLanguage = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"language:%@",currentDeviceLanguage);
#endif

    if([currentDeviceLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
        [localeDefaults setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    else
    {
        [localeDefaults setObject:@[@"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }

    [localeDefaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported, Apple is an English speaking company so English is the default "baseline" language.

I can understand why you would want to default to Russian in other Russian speaking countries like for example the Ukraine or Belarus.

You could make a Ukraine (uk) and Belarus (be) localization and just copy the Russian translation, although I think this would be an ugly hacked solution.

Comment: I also think so .. but just want to make sure

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the [`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430) key in the `Info.plist` file. Set its value to the default language you want the system to use if the app does not contain a localization for the users preferred language.